# Issue comes while search record according to year - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Hi guys i have a table expenses with multiple records.**

```
expenseID       ratename         description            workcompleted

51699           Base Rate        SNL Financial inquiry  08/09/2011
51699           Base Rate        SNL Financial inquiry  08/19/2011
51699           Base Rate        SNL Financial inquiry  08/09/2012
51699           Base Rate        SNL Financial inquiry  08/19/2012
```

But when i search record only for year 2012 but it return record for both the year(2011, 2012). But I need my record comes by year only i.e.

**expected results:**

```
51699   Base Rate   SNL Financial inquiry   08/09/2012
51699   Base Rate   SNL Financial inquiry   08/19/2012
```

Please see my query :

```
select expenseid,ratename,description,workcompleted from EXPENSES 
where workcompleted >= '08/08/2012' and workcompleted <= '08/19/2012'
```

I also try this by using between query but it doesn't work. If any body have an idea kindly share to me.

Comment: Your query looks OK :(  Q: Does it include *every* record between Aug 19, 2011 and Aug 19, 2012?  Q: What happens if you try "2012-08-19" instead of "08/19/2012" for both the "from" and "two" dates?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes it bring all the records  between Aug 19, 2011 and Aug 19, 2012. But i need this year wise only.

Comment: Understood.  Q: "workcompleted" is a date field, isn't it?  Not a char or varchar field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost certainly using the wrong data type. Your column "work_completed" should be of type date. It's almost certainly char or varchar.  Your best bet is to change the data type.

If you can't do that, you can create a view that mirrors the table, but casts the "work_completed" column to a date type.  Querying a date range against such a view should work correctly.

If you can't create views, you can change your WHERE clause to do the cast.  In standard SQL, it would look like

```
WHERE CAST(workcompleted AS DATE) >= '2012-08-08' 
  AND CAST(workcompleted AS DATE) <= '2012-08-19'
```

I know SQL Server supports CAST(), but you'll probably have to go with your original format for the dates (like '08/08/2012').

Expect a performance hit if you do that. SQL Server will have to do two type casts on every row.

Comment: Lovely..Thanks a lot this is the exact solution what i am looking for.. Actually i have already created a view of that & that has 20000 records. So at this position changing data type may be affected all over the project. But in this way (using cast) gives a exact solution without changing anything. I you dont mind i want to clap for you. Thanks a lot genius.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this please. You query is producing the results you need. May be there is something else you need like what @paulsm4 asked?

Reference * [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49a41/3)

YOUR QUERY:

```
select id,name,des,
wkdate from EXPENSES 
where wkdate >= '2012-08-08' 
and wkdate <= '2012-08-19'
;
```

RESULTS

```
ID      NAME        DES                     WKDATE
51699   Base Rate   SNL Financial inquiry   August, 09 2012 00:00:00+0000
51699   Base Rate   SNL Financial inquiry   August, 19 2012 00:00:00+0000
```

Above sample is constructed in **MYSQL**. And another simple way to get records by year, you may simply use a query like following too... Now this is in **SQL Server**

```
select id,name,des,
wkdate from EXPENSES 
where YEAR(wkdate) = '2012'
;
```

You may take a look at this [MSDN ARTICLE ABOUT YEAR IN SQL SERVER TSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx)

** Based on OP's comment**
In anycase if your date column is nvarchar.....let's convert/cast it to a date

```
select id,name,des,
wkdate from EXPENSES 
where YEAR(CAST(wkdate AS Date)) = '2012'
;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i have already try this method. It also doesn't work.

Comment: May be your date field is a nvarchar? in that case you may need to cast it to a date.... :$

Comment: DEFINATELY YOU ARE RIGHT. Thanks a lot this is the solution. Actually my datatype is nvarchar, so it creates a problem. Now i change this into datetime & problem solve. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Anytime John :) It's good to keep data types preserved, perhaps that's why there are many data types for us to use for different properties to work along :)

Comment: @bonCodigo - I just scrolled down and noticed your deduction.  Good job!

Comment: @paulsm4 Sorry, what do you mean by deduction?

Comment: I was complimenting how you figured out the date comparison wasn't working ... because the OP wasn't comparing dates.  He was comparing strings.  I deduced the same in his response to me above ... and then I scrolled down and saw that you figured it out first.  Good work!

Comment: Thanks :) But I guess Catcall got the lead even afterwards ;)